# Can't import module situated in parent folder from Jupyter-lab notebook and pathlib.Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-import

Here's my situation. I have some jupyter notebooks inside some folder and I would like to share some code between those notebooks trough a library I made.

The folder structure is the following:

```
1.FirstFolder/
    notebookA.ipynb
2.SecondFolder/
    notebookB.ipynb
mylib/
    __init__.py
    otherfiles.py
```

I tried putting the following code at the beginning of the notebook:

```
# to use modules in parent folder
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
libpath = os.path.join(Path.cwd().parent,'mylib')
print(f"custom library functions are in the module:\n\t{libpath}")
sys.path.append(libpath)
import mylib
```

The print outputs the correct path of the module and then a ModuleNotFoundError comes up and the program crashes:

```
---> 10 import mylib
     11 from mylib import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib'
```

Looking up on SO I found that that should have been the way to import a module from a non-default folder. **Where is the error?**

EDIT: after FinleyGibson's answer I tried `sys.path.append(Path.cwd().parent)` and restarted the kernel but I still have the same problem.

EDIT2:
I tried this and it worked, but I still would like to know why the previous approaches haven't worked.

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
tmp = Path.cwd()
os.chdir(Path.cwd().parent)
sys.path.append(Path.cwd())
import mylib
from mylib.dataloading import *
os.chdir(tmp)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added the **contents** of `os.path.join(Path.cwd().parent,'mylib')` to your path, this means python will look *inside* this dir for the module you are importing. `mylib` is not located in this dir, but rather the parent dir. Also `Path.cwd().parent` returns a `pathlib.PosixPath` object. Convert this to a string to use it with import (or, just use `sys.path.append('../')`:

try:

```
import sys
import os
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path.cwd().parent))
import mylib
```

doing this allows me to import a variable `X = 'import success'` located in otherfiles.py like so:

```
ans = mylib.otherfiles.X
print(ans)

>>> 'import success'
```

Comment: I am now unsure if this approach should work at all. I would normally do either `from mylib import otherfiles`, or `from mylib.otherfiles import *`. Do either of those work? If not I will have another look at it when less tired.

Comment: I noticed that I had the module copied also in the folder of the notebooks and that was why it worked. Now that I've removed, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Okay, so I have recreated the exact setup you described and got the same error as you. There are two mistakes I can see; The first as we have already mentioned is that you need to add the parent directory to path if you want to import mylib, not the mylib directory itself. The second is that `Path.cwd().parent` returns a pathlib.PosixPath object which cannot be interpreted by import. Converting this to a string fixed the issue for me. I have updated my answer with working code for you to try.

Answer (score 3):

I think Jupiter is not able to locate the folder of your module.

First cell use

```
cd ..
```

then in the next cell - then it should work

```
import mylib
```

Comment: Tried putting `os.chdir(Path.cwd().parent)` before the import and I still have the problem

Comment: Putting a cell with `cd ..` before the cell with the import has worked but it is not standard python nor portable to windows I think. And the notebook I'm working on is a shared project that has to run on multiple OS